# Ruby Rails - Structuring Nested Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, database

With my current project, I'm receiving a large JSON file that I'm parsing and storing into my database. The problem is I feel like I'm structuring my database in a very inefficient way.

Example of JSON:

```
{
    first_name: "John",
    records: {
     ids: [110, 725, 2250],
     count: [1, 1, 6]
      },
    items: {
        top: {
            title: "My top",
            values: {  value: [51, 50, 70] }
        },
        middle: {
            title: "Middle Stuff",
            values: { value: [51] }
        },
    },
    values: {
        health: 100,
        strength: 250,
        mana: 50
    }
}
```

As you can see the JSON is fairly complex, with nested Objects.

While building it, I started with the main Object ( `user` ), then slowly started adding more objects. `Values` was easy, so I added that as another table and just with a reference to the `user_id`.

Then I did `records`, which is a bit more complex, but works. However, I'm very worried about the most nested parts, that could be 5+ objects deep. I feel like I shouldn't have an entire column row for a simple value.

What would be the best way to improve on this? Should I somehow crunch the data and store it differently?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you plan to use the data later? Do you need all data at once or do you plan to run complex queries or calculations on the data? Did you consider a document data store or a JSONB column? Do you want to optimize the data structure for writing or reading, what is the more important use case?

Comment: I plan to run a few calculations upon receiving the data, storing the result, but I will need to display parts of the data later. For example, I need the top's title, and values later for displaying. All at the same time when displaying the entire user object. I'm mostly worried about reading the object back, writing shouldn't happen too often. And I haven't really looked into any other types such as JSONB.

Comment: It might be a better idea to create a proper `User` model instead with all the attributes needed and to the calculation on save.

Comment: Like, when I get all the JSON, find the aspects I need, and then save them? That sounds like what I'd like to do, but I also want to keep things Object-oriented, how would I say, take the `values` object, and keep that as an Object in code, but store it as, like JSON in the database?

Comment: If a user has only on `health` (for example) then there is no benefit in having a dedicated values table with an 1:1 association to a user. Just add the `health`, `strength`, `mana` columns directly to the user table. If a user might have multiple health values then create a new table and make it an has_many associate. Hard to give you an advice on the data and table structure without knowing your requirements and how you define the associations. `item`, `value`, `record` are pretty generic, I am not sure how they are connected in your domain.

Comment: Hi Spicerkmann, I've been working on a solution to this problem, and have posted my currently solution as an answer. Check it out if it's what you kinda had in mind, and any tips for improving would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// JSON response

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    ...
    "progression": {
        "levels": [{
            "name": "Level 1",
            "bosses": [
            {
                "name": "Boss 1",
                "difficultyCompleted": "Hard"
            },
            {
                "name": "Boss 2",
                "difficultyCompleted": "Hard"
            }]
        },{
            "name": "Level 2",
            "bosses": [
            {
                "name": "Boss 3",
                "difficultyCompleted": "Normal"
            },
            {
                "name": "Boss 4",
                "difficultyCompleted": "Easy"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

In this example JSON, there is a few layers for each boss that the user has completed. What I would have thought to do initially was to create models and tables but that seemed like it would be wasteful not only in memeory, but also would take longer to fetch the current progression for `Boss 4`.

Example:

```
User has_one Progression. 
Progression has_one Levels. 
Levels has_many Dungeons. 
Dungeons has_many bosses.
```

What I did instead was trying to compress the `bosses` into a single field, and just convert the JSON at runtime.

So, instead my structure would be like this.

```
User has_one Progression.
Progression has_many Dungeons.
```

---

Models:
// Progression.rb

```
class Progression < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :dungeons

    def self.initialize(params={})
        params = params['levels']

        prog = Progression.new()

        params.each do |dungeon|
            prog.dungeons.append( Dungeon.initialize( dungeon ) )
        end

        return prog
    end
end
```

// Dungeon.rb

```
class Dungeon < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :progression

    def self.initialize(params={})
        Dungeon.new(params.reject { |k| !Dungeon.attribute_method?(k) }) # Used to ignore any unused parameters that don't exist on the model.
    end

    # To convert `bosses` from JSON into a hash for easy use.
    def get_bosses
        JSON.parse bosses.gsub( '=>', ':' )
    end
end
```

---

Migration:
// xxxxxx_create_progression.rb

```
class CreateProgression < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :progressions do |t|
        t.integer :character_id
    end

    create_table :dungeons do |t|
        t.integer :character_id
        t.integer :progression_id

        t.string :name
        t.text :bosses
    end

    add_index :progressions, :character_id
    add_index :dungeons, :progression_id
end
end
```

Now, when a User is updated to fetch their progression, I can set their progression.

// users_controller.rb

```
def update_progression
    progression = ... fetched from the response

    @user.progression = Progression.initialize(progression)
end
```

After that's all saved to the user, you can now fetch the progression back by going:

```
<% user.progression.dungeons.each do |dungeon| %>
    <%= dungeon.name %>
<% end %>
```

This solution seems like a decent mix, but I'm a bit worried about the parsing of the JSON. It could become too much, but I'll have to keep watching it. Any other ideas or improvements would be greatly appreicated.